# Xubuntu 14.04 LTS not able to Boot

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I finished installing Xubuntu 14.04 LTS (x86 version). After restarting my system, it hangs for maybe 10 to 15 seconds and then displays this in the command prompt:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/05faf353-bde5-4e3e-9695-2458d8b18cb2 does not exist.

Dropping the shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Suggestions on correcting this?

My system is an old Pentium 4 (2 GB RAM, 3.06 GHz Hyper-Threading CPU, 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE i915 Intel Graphics Controller [64 MB], Two 400 GB IDE Hard Drives)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/109500/boot-issues-long-delay-then-gave-up-waiting-for-root-device or  http://askubuntu.com/questions/395295/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-while-booting

Comment: Apparently, typing "exit" and then holding down on the Enter key forces the boot to log into Xubuntu.